# Why am I being redirected to the login screen using keycloak-angular library?

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak

I have a problem with the refresh token: it seems to me it isn't being updated when I get a new normal token.
I've set token expiration to 5 mins. Refresh token expiration time has to be 40mins. It's a corporative keycloak server, I don't have management over it and they can only set my application's time for the token but not for the refresh token.
I have debugged both normal and refresh token every time I use updateToken. Both are refreshed. But when I get in the 40 mins limit I get redirected to login screen.

AFAIU, when normal token expires, the library should use the refresh token and then I would receive a new token and a new refresh token. So with the 5/40 minutes scheme, at each 5 minutes I would receive a new token (got with the refresh token) and a new refresh token with a 40 minutes later expiration time (45 minutes from the time the application started). So when the 40min arrive I should already have received 8 new tokens and refresh tokens and so my refresh token would be only 5 mins old and I should get a new token without problems.
But what happens is that it's like if it would use the very first refresh token received and tried to use it every time.

I think maybe this got a little confused. Let me try to explain better:

- 1st login at 15:00. Got token AAA (expires 15:05) and refresh token BBB (expires 15:40)
- 15:05=> token AAA expires, in onTokenExpired event I update token. The library uses token BBB to get new tokens.
- AFAIU, I receive token CCC (expires 15:10) and a new refresh token DDD (expired 15:45)
- 15:10=> token CCC expires, in onTokenExpired event I update token. The library uses token DDD to get new tokens.
- AFAIU, I receive token EEE (expires 15:15) and a new refresh token FFF (expired 15:50)

... and so on until

- 15:35=> token MMM expires, in onTokenExpired event I update token. The library uses token NNN to get new tokens.
- AFAIU, I receive token OOO (expires 15:40) and a new refresh token PPP (expired 16:15)
- 15:40=> token OOO expires, in onTokenExpired event I update token. The library uses token PPP to get new tokens.
- AFAIU, I should receive token QQQ (expires 15:40) and a new refresh token RRR (expired 16:15)

But in this moment I get a OnAuthLogout event and a 400 error when I access the keycloak server URL. It's like if it used refresh token AAA all the time, event though the debugs show that token and refresh token properties are updated correctly.

I debugged token, refreshToken, tokenParsed and refreshTokenParsed and they are updated correctly at each normal token refresh.

Here is a pastebin of the debugs. I changed only sensitive data relative to the company and some characters in the middle of the tokens in order to make them invalid. Please compare by the first and last characters:

https://pastebin.com/FStZzpE2
https://gist.github.com/nelson777/6066bb6631634da51510ba27b8ec064b
https://ghostbin.com/paste/sOyxZ

(3 options, because Pastebin security removed the original post thinking I had shared sensitive data)

What am I doing wrong ? here is my code:

```
const initOptions: any =
{
    adapter: 'default',
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    checkLoginIframe: false,
    checkLoginIframeInterval: 86400,
    enableLogging: true
};

let keycloackConfig = {
    config: environment.keycloakConfig,
    initOptions,
    bearerExcludedUrls: [],
    loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false
};
console.log('keycloackConfig', keycloackConfig);

let authenticated = await keycloak.init(keycloackConfig);
if (!authenticated)
    return res(0);

let u2t = ut => {
    let d = new Date(ut * 1000);
    return `${('' + d.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')}:${('' + d.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')}:${('' + d.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0')}`;
}
let keycloakInstance = keycloak.getKeycloakInstance();
console.log('keycloak', keycloak, keycloakInstance);
console.log('tokens', keycloakInstance.token, keycloakInstance.refreshToken);
console.log('tokenParsed', u2t(keycloakInstance.tokenParsed.iat), u2t(keycloakInstance.tokenParsed.exp));
console.log('refreshTokenParsed', u2t(keycloakInstance.refreshTokenParsed.iat), u2t(keycloakInstance.refreshTokenParsed.exp));

console.log(keycloak.keycloakEvents$);
from(keycloak.keycloakEvents$)
    .subscribe((event: any) => {
        if (event.type == KeycloakEventType.OnTokenExpired) 
            keycloakInstance.updateToken(30);

        console.log('keycloak token event', event.type);
        console.log('tokens', keycloakInstance.token, keycloakInstance.refreshToken);
        console.log('tokenParsed', u2t(keycloakInstance.tokenParsed.iat), u2t(keycloakInstance.tokenParsed.exp));
        console.log('refreshTokenParsed', u2t(keycloakInstance.refreshTokenParsed.iat), u2t(keycloakInstance.refreshTokenParsed.exp));
    })

keycloak.getKeycloakInstance().loadUserInfo().success(async (user: KeycloakUsuario) => {
    usuarioService.obterPorLoginComContasAdmin(user.username).subscribe(
                 <whatever>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to leave it registered here: I have found the solution.

The problem wasn't the tokens. They were being updated and used correctly. My application is a video and lives site. When A user starts watching a video or a live it stays in the same page for a long time. So due to this inactivity, Keycloak considers the session "idle" and it sends a Logout event.

The solution is to use `scope: offline_access` because this way keycloak will ignore the "idle time" configuration. But the `scope` option is available only in `login()` method, not in `init()`.

So in initOptions you remove the line:

```
onLoad: 'login-required',
```

then it won't authenticate automatically when you call `keycloak.init(keyclockConfig)`. So you'll have to do it manually giving the scope option:

```
    await keycloak.init(keycloackConfig);
    await keycloak.login({
        scope: 'offline_access',
    });
```

Then it will no loger consider idle time configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could have just increased the idle time.
In Realm settings in the Tokens tab.
So you wont have to do these extra steps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).